# contact form rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to make a contact form for Rails 4. But there're only tutorials for Rails 3.

But I got this error:

```
undefined method `name' for #<Message:0xa461fcc>
```

As I can understand it can't "see" the model.

```
index.html.erb
<%= form_for Message.new, :url => new_contact_path do |form| %>
  <fieldset class="fields">
    <div class="field">
      <%= form.label :name %>
      <%= form.text_field :name %>
    </div>

  ... same fieldsets...

  <fieldset class="actions">
    <%= form.submit "Send" %>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

in my model message.rb i got:

```
class Message

 extend ActiveModel::Naming
 include ActiveModel::Conversion
 include ActiveModel::Validations
 include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper

  validates :name, :email, :subject, :body, :presence => true
  validates :email, :format => { :with => %r{.+@.+\..+} }, :allow_blank => true

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end

end
```

and in routes i just got:

```
resources :contact
```

That's the controller code:

```
class ContactController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @message = Message.new
  end

  def create
    @message = Message.new(contact_params)

    if @message.valid?
      NotificationsMailer.new_message(@message).deliver
      redirect_to(root_path, :notice => "Message was successfully sent.")
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Please fill all fields."
      render :new
    end
  end

  private
    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def contact_params
      params.require(:message).permit(:name, :email, :subject, :body)
    end

end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `attr_accessor :name, :email, :subject, :and_so_on` to your class to that these methods are defined.

When using `form.label`, Rails will try doing `your_message.label`, but this method is not defined since you're not using active record but only few bits from active model.

Using attribute accessors should do the trick.

Comment: it really worked. thanks! I thought attr_accessor used only in Rails 3 or less. I think i was wrong. Thanks again.

Comment: attr_accessor is pure ruby, you probably confound with ``attr_accessible`` which is rails and indeed deprecated in favor of strong parameters in rails4. Please accept my answer if you're done with it :)

Comment: Yup. I was waiting till I can :) Thanks again with explanation. You're right, i was confused. My bad.